# How to check if JSON file contains only empty array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to check if my JSON file contains data or only empty array. I am doing it in this way:

```
with open('example.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    if not data:
        do_my_stuff()
```

But my JSON files can be really huge and I do not want to load them all.
Can I check if file contains nothing but empty array in other way? Check if my file's weight is 2 bytes (isn't it lame?)?

Comment: Why not test with `json.load` only those files smaller than `X` bytes that you test with `os.path.getsize(path)`? `X` would probably 5 bytes equal to `null\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`os.path.getsize(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) to find file size of a file.
You do not have to read file at all.
If JSON file is just 2 bytes, "[]" or "{}", it is an empty JSON object.

Based on some JSON usage principles, in this particular case it is sane and safe to presume that a 2 bytes long JSON string is an empty string, array or object ("", [], {}). A two digits number may be a valid JSON string but it is not what JSON is used for (you can use JSON library to load a single value like you can use a big crane to lift an egg).

If this [file size] does not fulfill your requirements you have to read the first 2 bytes and check if they are equal to '[]':

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    if file.read(2) != '[]':
        file.seek(0)  # it may be redundant but it does not hurt
        json.load(file)
```